# Java Arraylist remove multiple element by index

Tags: java, android, arraylist, stop-words

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarraylist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.size(); j++) {
            if (stopwords.get(j).equals(myarraylist.get(i))) {
                myarraylist.remove(i);
                id.remove(i);
                i--; // to look at the same index again!
            }
        }
    }
```

I have problem.. after element removed, all index always changed, the loop above so messy.

To illustrate: 
I have 54 data, but loop above become messy after element removed.. so only 50 data that checked.

Is there another way or fix my code to **remove multiple element by index**??
element index is so important to me, to remove another arraylist that have the same index.

Comment: Kindly take a look onto this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/223918/1679863

Comment: Use `Iterator` to remove elements while looping.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One thing you need to keep in mind is that when you use `ArrayLists` that they are meant to be versatile, moreso than `Arrays`. You can shorten an array by removing an entire index, add an index to it, and do wonderfulness with `ArrayLists`.

This is a common problem with people who do not realize, or remember, that when you remove a value, the `ArrayList` indexes (or whatever the correct plural is) readjust and the `ArrayList` shortens.

When attempting to remove elements from an `ArrayList`, you should always start at the end of the `ArrayList`.

```
for(int x = arrayList.size() - 1; x > 0; x--)
{
    arrayList.remove(x);
}
```

This should provide you with the function that you are looking for. Take a look at the [ArrayList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for other methods that may help you.

Comment: @SteveKuo, why? should `x` be `x = arrayList.size() - 1`. I did not actually think about checking that, I just wanted to show the OP the practice for removing elements from an array list.

Comment: You are correct, you're off by one. In general it's far better to use Iterator's remove rather than relying on reverse order index based looping.

Comment: @SteveKuo thanks for the spotting mate, changed it. Never heard of iterator, guess it's time to look into it.

Comment: This is not a good solution considering performance.

arrayList.remove(index)

 remove() method will shift other subsequent elements.

Comment: This solution fails on following data.

data = [5,2,7,3,9,34,63,23,85,23,94,7]

int index[] = [5,2,7,9] // indexes to remove

Answer (score 14):

Use `Iterator.remove()` to remove elements while iterating.

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = myarraylist.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
  String element = iter.next();
  if (element meets some criteria) {
    iter.remove();
  }
}
```

Or use Google Guava's [filter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) which returns a filtered view and leaves the original list unchanged.

```
Iterable<String> filtered = Iterables.filter(myarraylist, new Predicate<String>() {
  public boolean apply(String element) {
    return true of false based on criteria
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is very good problem to solve.
Lets start with an exmaple

We have `data = [5,2,7,3,9,34,63,23,85,23,94,7]`

indexes to remove

```
int index[] = [5,2,7,9]
```

**Note** : As you remove single item from array other elements get shifted by 1.

If we use ArrayList to remove elements of indexes then first you need to sort the indexes in descending.

i.e indexes = [9,7,5,2]
then remove the element from index

```
ArrayList<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {5,2,7,3,9,34,63,23,85,23,94,7});

for(int i=0;i<index.length;i++){
    data.remove(index[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like as you want to remove one collection from another.. You should use 
java.util.Collection#removeAll method instead

Answer (score 1):

Here is short benchmark that roughly compares various methods to remove elements from array list. Removal by index is really a bad idea since array list shrinks its internal array on every operation. There will be no real difference for small arrays but if you have large chunk of indices to remove it will cost much.

```
Benchmark                                    Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
CollectionsTest.filterToNewListViaLoop       avgt    2   4.425          ms/op
CollectionsTest.filterToNewListViaStream     avgt    2   5.410          ms/op
CollectionsTest.removeByIndexInReverseOrder  avgt    2  69.234          ms/op
CollectionsTest.removeByIterator             avgt    2   4.311          ms/op
CollectionsTest.removeViaRemoveAllMethod     avgt    2   4.145          ms/op
```

**CODE:**

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Warmup(iterations = 2)
@Measurement(iterations = 2)
public class CollectionsTest {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private static final int CONTAINER_SIZE = 100_000;
    private static final int REMOVE_COUNT = 10_000;

    private List<Foo> _container;
    private TreeSet<Integer> _indicesToRemove;
    private HashSet<Foo> _elementsToRemove;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(CollectionsTest.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Setup(Level.Invocation)
    public void setup() {
        _container = generateContainerData(CONTAINER_SIZE);
        _indicesToRemove = generateIndicesToRemove(REMOVE_COUNT, CONTAINER_SIZE);

        _elementsToRemove = new HashSet<>();
        _indicesToRemove.stream().map(Foo::new).forEach(_elementsToRemove::add);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void removeByIndexInReverseOrder() {
        int iterations = 0;
        for (int arrayIndex : _indicesToRemove.descendingSet()) {
            _container.remove(arrayIndex);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void removeByIterator() {
        _container.removeIf(foo -> _elementsToRemove.contains(foo));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void filterToNewListViaStream() {
        List<Foo> elementsToKeep = _container.stream()
                .filter(foo -> !_indicesToRemove.contains(foo.id))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void filterToNewListViaLoop() {
        List<Foo> elementsToKeep = new ArrayList<>(CONTAINER_SIZE - REMOVE_COUNT);
        for (Foo foo : _container) {
            if (!_indicesToRemove.contains(foo.id)) elementsToKeep.add(foo);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void removeViaRemoveAllMethod() {
        _container.removeAll(_elementsToRemove);
    }

    private List<Foo> generateContainerData(int size) {
        List<Foo> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {
            data.add(new Foo(idx));
        }
        return data;
    }

    private TreeSet<Integer> generateIndicesToRemove(int count, int containerSize) {
        TreeSet<Integer> data = new TreeSet<>();
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, containerSize)
                .distinct()
                .limit(count)
                .forEach(data::add);
        return data;
    }

    public static class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
        private static final Comparator<Foo> COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparing(foo -> foo.id);

        public int id;

        public Foo(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Foo that) {
            return COMPARATOR.compare(this, that);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Foo{");
            sb.append("id=").append(id);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about why you want to do this by index, but you can try this (untested):

```
int dynamicSize = myarraylist.size();
for (int i = 0; i < dynamicSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < stopwords.size(); j++) {
            if (stopwords.get(j).equals(myarraylist.get(i))) {
                myarraylist.remove(i);
                id.remove(i);
                i--; // to look at the same index again!
                dynamicSize--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

while iterating list and you are removing the object use iterator.

```
Iterator myListItr = myarraylist.iterator();
//Iterate on list 
    while(myListItr .hasNext()) {
    //if stop words is list of string then contains will work as it is. If its your custom object then override equals method.
        if(stopwords.contains( myListItr.next())){
    myListItr.remove();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      // List : ["java", ".net", "javascript", "html", "css", "selenium", "image", "Spring"]

    ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                      // indexes : [5, 3, 2, 5, 0]
    // Sort the Indexes in Order to remove from back words. and make Unique
    TreeSet<Integer> uniqueSorted = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        uniqueSorted.addAll(indexes);

    // To remove all elements from the ArrayList and make its size = 0  
        indexes.clear(); 
        indexes.addAll(uniqueSorted);

    // Iterate form back, so that if size decreases also no problem.
    ListIterator<Integer> li = indexes.listIterator(indexes.size());

   // we can traverse a List in both the directions (forward and Backward).
        while(li.hasPrevious()) {
            int position = li.previous();
            list.remove(position);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the input as an `ArrayList` and a list of indices to be deleted. If the input `ArrayList` list does not contain nulls, then you can do it this way:

```
List<?> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
for (int i : indicesToRemove) {
  newList.set(i, null);
}
newList.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

This way does not require sorting the indexes to be removed and takes advantage of the fact that `ArrayList` has its own optimal `removeIf` implementation.